# treeview getdirectories gets error

Tags: wpf, treeview, runtime-error

Im trying to make a wpf app display a treeview with my files. I cant manage to put driveinfo properly into directory info:

```
            DirectoryInfo sdf = new DirectoryInfo(DriveInfo.GetDrives()[x].ToString());

            foreach (DirectoryInfo z in sdf.GetDirectories()) //Run time error here
            { }
```

It gives a runtime error.
Below is full code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        treeView1.Items.Clear();
        for (int x = 0; x < DriveInfo.GetDrives().Length; x++)
        {
            TreeViewItem y = new TreeViewItem() { Header = DriveInfo.GetDrives()[x] };
            treeView1.Items.Add(y);
            comboBox1.Items.Add(DriveInfo.GetDrives()[x]);

            DirectoryInfo sdf = new DirectoryInfo(DriveInfo.GetDrives()[x].ToString());

            foreach (DirectoryInfo z in sdf.GetDirectories()) //Run time error here
            {
                TreeViewItem newmain = new TreeViewItem();
                newmain.Header = z.Name;
                newmain.Tag = z.FullName;
                y.Items.Add(newmain);

            }
        }
```

The error is:

IOException was unhandled

http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28EHIOEXCEPTION%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true

Comment: "It gives me a runtime error". What is the exception? [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access a drive which is not ready - for example, a CD/DVD drive with no media inserted. You'll need to check the `IsReady` property of the `DriveInfo` class before trying to access the `RootDirectory`:

```
foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
{
   TreeViewItem y = new TreeViewItem { Header = drive.Name };
   treeView1.Items.Add(y);
   comboBox1.Items.Add(drive.Name);

   if (!drive.IsReady) continue;

   DirectoryInfo root = drive.RootDirectory;
   if (!root.Exists) continue;

   foreach (DirectoryInfo z in root.GetDirectories())
   {
      y.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem
      {
         Header = z.Name,
         Tag = z.FullName
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been struggling around with this for a while now! You made my day!